# Kernel of the differential of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the projection map $\pi:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ given by $\pi(x,y,z)=(y,z).$ The differential $D\pi=\pi$ since $\pi$ is a linear map. I want to find the kernel of this map. The gradient vector of $\pi$ is [0 1 1] so to find the kernel we find $a,b,c$ such that $$(0,1,1)\cdot(a,b,c)=0 $$.
That is $$b+c=0$$. How do I describe the kernel? Any help is appreciated

Comment: You learn that $b=-c$.  Notice now that $(a,b,c)=(a,-c,c)$ using the earlier observation.  You can then break this up if you so choose... $(a,-c,c)=a(1,0,0)+c(0,-1,1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I just realized my gradient vector is wrong! Right? It should be the matrix [0 1 0, 0 0 1]?

Comment: Yes it's wrong it should be a $3 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: @N.H. you mean a 2×3?

Comment: Yes I do ${{{}}}$

Comment: @N.H. I think what you should get is $y=z=0$. Thus kernel is the set of {$(x,0,0)$}

Comment: Yes I deleted my previous comment. But as you noticed, this is a linear algebra problem and has nothing to do with differential topology.